# How to split a string with more than one delimiter

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, split

*EDIT*: I should have phrased this question better. Instead of deleting it, I'll leave it here for others to learn from.

Been working on this for a while, I have yet to find another post that answers this.

The list I am trying to split looks like the following:

```
0. Yersinia Pestis, 76561198010013870
1. CatharsisLtd., 76561198056110126
2. Nut~Taco, 76561198072105032
```

It's a list of player names and ID numbers. I am trying to remove the x. from the start of each line, and the `,` just before the ID number so that way I am left with a list that looks like this:

```
Yersinia Pestis
76561198010013870
CatharsisLtd.
76561198056110126
Nut~Taco
76561198072105032
```

I thought I had found a solution by using something like this:

```
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {',' , '\n' });
```

But that doesn't work since players are able to have things like ", ." and other symbols in their names. I'm sure there is a way to do something like

```
string splitter = i.ToString()+". ";
and then something like ", any17DigitNumber"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm completely stumped on how to make this work for all scenarios. The only constants are the indexing and the length of the IDs.

Comment: Are you in control of the original format of the data? If so, you would be better off changing that to make parsing it later easier

Comment: Unfortunately I am not. This is the format the response from the server comes in. I have no way of changing that :(

Comment: And users are allowed any printable characters in their names?

Comment: Regex will be the choice ..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Player(Index={0}, Id={1}, Name={2})", Index, Id, Name);
    }
}

public static Player ParsePlayer(string line)
{
    var dot = line.IndexOf(".");
    var comma = line.LastIndexOf(",");
    return
        new Player
        {
            Index = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, dot).Trim()),
            Id = long.Parse(line.Substring(comma + 1).Trim()),
            Name = line.Substring(dot + 1, comma - (dot + 1)).Trim()
        };
}

public static void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        "0. Yersinia Pestis, 76561198010013870",
        "1. CatharsisLtd., 76561198056110126",
        "2. Nut~Taco, 76561198072105032",
        "3. Smith, John, 76561198072105033",
        " 4.Allen, Paul,76561198072105034 "
    };

    var players = new List<Player>();

    // parse
    foreach (var line in data)
    {
        players.Add(ParsePlayer(line));
    }

    // check
    foreach (var player in players)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(player);
    }
}
```

Testable [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PYAgVr).

As Reddy suggested in a comment, alternatively, you can also try regular expressions, with named capture groups:

```
public static Player ParsePlayer(string line)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?<index>[0-9]+)\s*\.\s*(?<name>.+)\s*,\s*(?<id>[0-9]+)\s*");
    var match = regex.Match(line);
    return
        new Player
        {
            Index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value),
            Id = long.Parse(match.Groups["id"].Value),
            Name = match.Groups["name"].Value
        };
}
```

Testable [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4AWOSo).

'Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems like the best options. Thanks for the quick response. By the way, totally didn't know about dotnetfiddle, that is awesome :D

I'll tag this solution once I get it working.

Comment: @thermite The best, I don't know. A simple and easy enough one to reason about, to start with, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

If your list are always separated into three columns like those provided in your example:

```
0. Yersinia Pestis, 76561198010013870
1. CatharsisLtd., 76561198056110126
2. Nut~Taco, 76561198072105032
```

And you want them split and get only last two columns, then why don't you first split the strings with `<Space>`, then:

1. omit first column with shift(). You can have a look at [How to shift the start of an array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470982/how-to-shift-the-start-of-an-array-in-c)
2. pop() last column, which is basically ID number
3. join() rest of the columns back with `<space>` and remove last character, which is a comma.

This way you are left with what you wanted.

Comment: If I split them with a space, would that not cause issues with usernames like the first one which contains a space?

Comment: that is why we have third step in above steps.

Comment: just working on how to convert that initial string into an array. the var that contains that list is just a standard string, so I'm trying to break it on each new line.
    List<string> list = new List<string>(Regex.Split(input, Environment.NewLine));

Comment: still gives me a count of 1. dunno why it won't let me edit my previous post to add this in there.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach:

```
var source = @"0. Yersinia Pestis, 76561198010013870
1. CatharsisLtd., 76561198056110126
2. Nut~Taco, 76561198072105032";

var results =
    source
        .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf('.') + 2))
        .SelectMany(x => new []
        {
            x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(',')),
            x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(',') + 2)
        });
```

It gives me:

[image: results]

Alternatively you could replace the `.SelectMany` with this:

```
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(',')),
            Id = x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(',') + 2)
        });
```

...then you get:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who posted solutions. I wasn't able to use either due to the way the server response I was getting, but they both got me heading in the right direction. Here's what I ended up having to do to get the ID I wanted for the person sending the command:
` //grab all online players from both servers
                    string centerPlayers = await messenger.ExecuteCommandAsync("ListPlayers");
                    string scorchedPlayers = await messengerB.ExecuteCommandAsync("ListPlayers");

```
                //use players discord ID number to locate them in playerData, then find users in game name from there
                bool foundPlayer = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < playerData.Count / 10 - 1; i++)
                {
                    if(playerData[i*10+9] == discordID)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Player found in playerData");
                        if (centerPlayers.Contains(playerData[i * 10]))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Player found online on center");
                            foundPlayer = true;
                            //break off user's steam ID from centerPlayers
                            string name = playerData[i * 10]+ ", ";
                            string[] temp = Regex.Split(centerPlayers, name);
                            string tempb = temp[1];
                            string[] tempc = tempb.Split(' ');
                            Console.WriteLine("Steam ID:" + tempc[0]);
                            //can give gold here, then break
                        }
                        else if (scorchedPlayers.Contains(playerData[i * 10]))
                        {
                            foundPlayer = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Player found online on scorched");
                            //break off user's steam ID from centerPlayers
                            //can give gold here, then break
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foundPlayer = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Player is not online");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Long story short, this is a discord bot that manages a game server via RCON. all player data is stored into an array. Players can link their in game characters to their discord ID which allows them to earn points via play time that is tracked by the bot. This method allows me to search through playerData[], see if the discord ID is there, if it is, I can traverse back several places and get the player's in game name. Once I have the name, I can then search though the list of online players. I split the list on the name + ", " and then split again on the next space. This gives me the proper ID from the list. Now I know the player is online, and registered. Now the player can trade in points via discord, and the bot can then use RCON on the proper server (this monitors two different servers) to give the player their gold.

Thanks again for the help :)